# How to formulate python round function for an equation?

Tags: python

I am trying to round a number that comes from an equation

```
r = len(column_name)/len(df)*100,"%"
print("% of some data =",round(r,2))
```

but apparently it is a wrong way, because I get following error:
type tuple doesn't define **round** method

how to approach this?

Comment: `r = len(column_name)/len(df)*100`, then `print("% of some data =",round(r,2)),"%")`

Comment: The `,"%"` at the end of the line makes `r` a tuple...

Comment: You are trying to round `(number, "%")`, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`len(column_name)/len(df)*100,"%"` is a tuple of the number (`len(column_name)/len(df)*100`) and the string `%`.

Use

```py
r = len(column_name) / len(df) * 100
print("% of some data =", round(r, 2), "%")
```